# Poweshell not able to run node js

Tags: powershell

hi i m a windows 11 user i m faced with an issue where power-shell terminal 86 is able to run node js and power shell 64 is not able to run node js despite installing node js 32 bit and 64 bit respectively i have tried adding path variable but still node js is not ruining on it

[image: poweshell 64]

[image: powershell 86]

[image: env path]

i m able to figure out that the source directory that powershell 64 is using is not right but how can i change that so that it can find node js

update - here is the path

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.8.101-hotspot\bin
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\WINDOWS
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DTS\Binn\
C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin
C:\tools
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\nvm
C:\Program Files\nodejs
C:\Program Files\nodejs
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts
C:\tools
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\nvm
C:\Program Files\nodejs
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WinGet\Packages\Typst.Typst_Microsoft.Winget.Source_8wekyb3d8bbwe\typst-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin
PS C:\Users\USER>
```

Comment: run `$env:PATH` in those windows and paste the output here

Comment: i have edited the post with an image with $env:PATH could you have a look at it and figure out why it is happening

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Just paste the output here in proper format as I commented. And it's better to run `$env:PATH -split ';'` to make the paths easier to view

Comment: @phuclv i have added it in my original since comment is showing limit of characters i have also tried installing it in both x64 and x86 but it did not worked